# Link to PHP functions

Tags: php

I have an index.php and output.php
I need two buttons both linked to output.php but to different functions and I can't get it work. Here is my code:

In index.php:

```
<?php 
    include 'output.php';
    if (isset ($_POST ['choice3'])){
        choice3();
    }
    if (isset ($_POST ['choice4'])){
        choice4();
    }
 ?>
<form method="post" action="output.php">
    <input type="submit" name="choice3" id="choice3" value="Choice 3">
    <input type="submit" name="choice4" id="choice4" value="Choice 4">      
</form>
```

In Output.php,

```
function choice3(){} and function choice4(){}
```

Each function have different output.
But now, when I click the button, nothing shows up.

Thanks for help!!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: try putting action field empty.

Comment: @sectus My question is the code doesn't work..so it shows nothing when I click the button, there should be output.

Comment: @NabinKunwar, still doesn't work..

Comment: post  code of output.php. is it object oriented style??

Comment: Could we see where choice3 and choice4 are defined? Presumably it's somewhere in ouput.php... maybe you could post the contents of that file?

Comment: try changing second if with else if();

Comment: @user2898314 Just a side note: 1) Never use root user for MySQL. You should create another user with a subset of permissions. 2) Always choose a non-default, complex password. 3) Never put the credentials on a public site like this (Even if its host is localhost).

Comment: @Thrustmaster, thanks for your suggestions, I was not going to post that part initially, and I am new to the environment and doing hw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Replace your index.html.php and output.php with this**

**Index.php**

```
<form method="post" action="output.php">
    <input type="submit" name="choice3" id="choice3" value="Choice 3">
    <input type="submit" name="choice4" id="choice4" value="Choice 4">      
</form>
```

**Output.php**

```
<?php

if (isset ($_POST ['choice3']))
{
/ body of the choice 3 function without the function signature
}
elseif(isset ($_POST ['choice4']))
{
/ body of the choice 4 function without the function signature
}
    ?>
```

Comment: isset() will always return true because choice3 and choice4 have a value in HTML

Comment: isset() in output.php will be called only when the button is clicked on the html page even if choice3 or choice4 has a value.

Comment: I am sorry to insist but both variables are sent with their values, change the method to get and check the URL, you will see both variables there.

Comment: @EddyXP Nope, you are wrong. Try it out yourself. Use the above HTML (only), change method to GET, action to "", and check the URL upon hitting submit.

Comment: You are absolutely right!!! OMG, you learn something new everyday, the funny thing is that both inputs are part of the form and in theory both should be submitted unless they had the same name like radio buttons. I guess this is one exception to the rule. Sorry and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just Replace your code with this

```
<?php
include 'output.php';
$choice = $_POST['choice'];
if ($choice == 'choice3') {
    choice3();
} else if ($choice == 'choice4') {
    choice4();
}
?>
<script>
    function make_choice(choice) {
        document.getElementById('choice').value = choice;
        document.choice_form.submit();
    }
</script>
<form method="post" action="" name="choice_form">
    <input type="hidden" name="choice" id="choice" value="" />
    <input type="button" name="choice3" id="choice3" value="choice3" onclick="make_choice(this.value);">
    <input type="button" name="choice4" id="choice4" value="choice4" onclick="make_choice(this.value);">
</form>
```

Comment: your conditional is assigning a value not comparing, use ==. Also the variable $_POST['choice'] is only for the first input, the other two inputs are not checked.

Comment: @EddyXP thanks for the edit suggested but the choice is only assigned the value selected by user and we will get a single click at a time so its fine

Comment: then add to the form onsubmit="return false" if not it will be submited without executing the function :)